# c# buttons image control with mouse event

Tags: c#, image

I have 3 button in my form, and i'm finding a way to control its images when a mouse event happens

- when i click button 1: set button 2 and 3 image with normal images, set button 1 with "mouse click" image.
- when i click button 2: set button 1 and 3 image with normal images, set button 2 with "mouse click" image.
  ...

[That's what i'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXNvD.png)

And I want something sorter and can be use for more buttons, Like default button events or like (just 1 function for all buttons):
button A is sender -> reset all and set button A

Comment: Dont put the image. Try to copy paste the code.

Comment: Maybe create a dictionary where `Key` is the `Button` instance, and value is a `Tuple<Image, Image>` (clicked, normal). Then you create just one event handler where you can set all buttons from dictionary to normal state, and finally you search for sender in that dictionary and you set it to clicked state. It will allows you to easily add new buttons. Of course you can create a custom reusable class for it - which applies not only to buttons.

Comment: Thank you, i really get your idea, could you just help me with some example code , it would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can create one event for all the function and could be used like

```
private void ButtonAll_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ResetAllButtonImage();
    Button b = sender as Button;
    if(b.Text == "A") // or tag or Name Something to find
    {
        b.Image=(Image)(Properties.Resources.MouseClickThietLap);
    }
    else if(b.Text == "B")
    {
        b.Image=(Image)(Properties.Resources.MouseClickKhachHang);
    }
    else
    {
        b.Image=(Image)(Properties.Resources.MouseClickDoanhSo);
    }
}
```

And all the buttons should be pointing to this Event. You can do it from the Form Design Properties or Form.Designer.cs

```
this.Button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonAll_Click);
this.Button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonAll_Click);
this.Button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonAll_Click);
```

Comment: I don't see the check-mark, this is my first time using stackoverflow, could you show me where.

Comment: OK, i've seen it ^^